# Automatic testing of web sites from a user's point of view?

Tags: testing, automation, web

Are there tools available that will simulate going to a web site, clicking links, filling in forms, submitting those forms, all the while comparing output to expected output until it finds a problem?

Comment: I believe you might find utility in some of the answers for the question @ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/69375/looking-for-ways-to-automate-web-site-testing

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've used [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/) for this.

Answer (score 0):

We have been using [visual studio web testing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/teamsystem/dd408381.aspx), and it's working pretty well for us.